# How to handle large CSV files into smaller CSV files and then merge all the files into one CSV files

Tags: r, csv

I have more 500 excel files all above 400 MB size all with same header. I want to split the file into multiple files of 1000 rows in each file. After splitting the file into multiple files, I want to merge all the first 400 files of 1000 rows files into a single file.

Comment: Excel or CSV? Which?

Comment: I want in CSV. Already converted into CSV file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like this to remove all the headers (i.e. use `sed` to delete line 1) and split the result into files of 1,000 rows, whose names start with `<originalfile>-chunk...`:

```
for f in *.csv; do sed '1d' "$f" | split -l 1000 - "$f-chunk-" ; done
```

The `d` command in `sed` means *"delete the specified line"*. If your original files were called `1.csv`, `2.csv`, you will now have files called:

```
1.csv-chunk-aa    # first 1000 lines of 1.csv
1.csv.chunk-ab    # second 1000 lines of 1.csv
2.csv-chunk-aa    # first 1000 lines of 2.csv
2.csv-chunk-ab    # second 1000 lines of 2.csv
```

If you then want to concatenate all the first chunks of all the original files together into a new file, and all the second chunks of all the original files into a second file and so on...

```
for f in *-chunk-* ; do 
   echo $f
done |sed 's/.*chunk-//' | sort | uniq | { i=0; while read x; do 
   cat *chunk-$x > reassem-$i
   ((i++))
done }
```

That will give `reassem-0` with the first 1000 lines of each of your files, `reassem-1` with the  second 1000 lines of each of your files...

If you want all the lines of all the original CSVs in a single big output file without any headers, do this:

```
for f in *.csv; do sed '1d' "$f"; done > BigBoy.csv
```

Comment: Second part is like...I have fragmented each larger files into smaller multiple files and each smaller files contain 1000 rows.  After that first file of 1000 rows of each larger file, i have to merge into a single file.

Comment: If you had just two files, with 401 lines each, what would you want to get? 2 files with 400 lines each and 1 file with 2 lines? Or 2 files with 400 lines each and 2 files with 1 line each?

Comment: I want the second option. 2 files with 400 lines each and 2 files with 1 line each.   After that I have to merge both files of 400 lines into a single file of 800 line and both files of 1 line each into 1 file of 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try to convert those to csv before messing with them. I've used [xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv) in the past to do this. Using R, I've done:

```
system(paste0('xlsx2csv -s 3 ', data_source, '" output.csv'))
```

Maybe you loop over your files and convert them using that function. Then do whatever manipulation you want to the csv files.

Comment: I have converted them into CSV already... Sorry I didn't mention that in my question...